# Gazebo object pose and getAsEuler

Tags: ros, gazebo, pose, quaternion

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm working on a quad-rotor simulation in 3D space. I use the `GetPose()` method to get the current object pose in the space. And now there is the problem.

The `GetPose()` method return a `Pose3D` object. This object contains

- A `Vector3` for the body position.
- A `Quatern` for the body orientation.

Now I should transform this quaternion in a Roll-Pitch-Yaw triple through the `GetAsEuler()` method of `Quatern`. Unfortunately this value is non-continue because it jump from `pi` to `-pi` and this cause trouble to my controller!

Exist any way to obtain a continue transformation from quaternion to euler triple?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11669/gazebo-object-pose-and-getaseuler/) by [thek3nger](https://answers.ros.org/users/1169/thek3nger/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2011-10-25

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It depends what you want. The reason for the uncontinuity is that the angles are normalized.
If you would use them incrementally values might grow arbitrarily, so they are not that nice to read (and which with huge values might lead to loss of precision).
One solution would be to "renormalize" to the last angle, i.e.:

- Remember the last angle
- Get current (normalized) angle
- add/substract 2*pi until (angle - last_angle) is smallest

The better solution would probably be to handle that nicely in the controller, but that depends on its functionality (e.g. if you calculate an angle difference in the controller normalize that difference).
The angles packages provides: shortest_angular_distance for this.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-10-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [thek3nger](https://answers.ros.org/users/1169/thek3nger/) on 2011-10-26**:
Thank you. :)